# Strange es query string?

Tags: elasticsearch

My documents are indexed with the following field "fruitName":

```
pear-fruit
apple-fruit
jack-fruit
```

I want to use a QueryString query to be able to look up "pear-fruit". When I enter in my querystring query: "pear-fruit", I do not get any documents back. If I query for "fruit", I get all documents back.

How can I just query for:
**pear-fruit**

to make sure that I only get that one document? Can I "escape" the dash or do something in my query to make it pick up? Or set up some other mapping? Note that fruitName is not analyzed, and is a string.

Comment: The field seems to be analysed as 2 terms instead of 1. You can possibly set the field as "not_analyzed" in the mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're doing it like below, and it returns you all documents.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/fruits/fruit/_search?q=pear-fruit
```

Since `fruitName` is a `not_analyzed` string, you can simply query it like this (i.e. with double quotes)

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/fruits/fruit/_search?q="pear-fruit"
```

or like this (with the field name)

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/fruits/fruit/_search?q=fruitName:"pear-fruit"
```

More info about what can be achieved in a [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names)